# How to handle ALT+TAB key from Bluetooth Keyboard in Android Activity?

Tags: android

I want to capture `ALT+TAB` keys pressed from Bluetooth Keyboard connected to Device, and i want to do some custom action in my application.

As by default this Key Combination shows Recent Tasks.
(May be in `PhoneWindowManager.java::ShowOrHideRecentAppsDialog)`.
So i want to disable this action and want to handle this in my App. May be with help of `onKeyShortCut()` Function or so.

Can someone help me with some sample piece of code ?

FYI: If require , can make changes in Platform also.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Have you found a solution?